# Is this if statement overkill?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a database table called Investigation. Within this table there is a column called INV. This column can hold a value of 0, 1, or null.

In my application, there is an if statement written like this:

```
QNet.Investigation.DataContracts.Investigation investigation = Session["InvestigationObj"] as QNet.Investigation.DataContracts.Investigation;

if (investigation != null && investigation.INV != null && investigation.INV == true)
{
    ....       
}
```

It seems to me that this is a bit of overkill because if investigation.INV == true then obviously the other two statements will not be null. If either of the other two are null then investigation.INV would also be null.

Am I missing something here? Is there a reason why the original developer created the if statement this way? Wouldn't

```
if(investigation.INV == true)
{
    ...
}
```

do the exact same thing?

Comment: `if(investigation.INV)`

Comment: @MattBeldon What? No, that doesn't contemplate a possible `NullReferenceException`

Comment: neither does `if(investigation.INV == true)`

Comment: @MattBeldon Please read the code... `investigation != null &&`

Comment: You state `If either of the other two are null then investigation.INV would also be null.` However that is not true.. Because if `investigation` is null, then `investigation.INV` will throw a NullReferenceException

Comment: The if is somewhat overkill, but you cannot take out `investigation != null &&` unless you know that `investigation` won't ever be `null`

Comment: You´re correct that `investigation.INV == true` implies that `investigation` is not `null`. However the reverse isn´t true, thus only because `investigation` is not null doesn´t mean `investigation.INV` is `true`. Thus you should of course check if `investigation` is null before further investigating `investigation.INV == true`.

Comment: In C# 8 with non-null references, probably `if(investigation.INV)` may be enough :D

Answer (score 6):

> Wouldn't
>
> ```
> if(investigation.INV == true)
> {
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> do the exact same thing?

No, it will cause a `NullReferenceException` if `investigation` is `null`. This is why you *have* to check for null in any way, either by the [null-coalesce-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) or by using your - admittedly - annyoing if-statement or what ever.

In other words:

Only because `investigation` is not `null` doesn´t mean `investigation.INV` is `true`. It can obviously be `false` or even `null` as well.

Comment: A +1 for answering the OP's real question *(or at least what appears to be his/her real question)*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.  Just because the Investigation object wouldn’t be null doesn’t mean its properties would be initialized and/or set to the desired values.

You can just null coalesce the statement though:

```
If (investigation?.INV == true)
{ 
    //do this
}
```

Does the exact same thing as what you’re doing - checks if the root object is null & if the properties are null, it acts like a 'try' and will skip the block so you won’t get an error.

Comment: can someone explain why `(investigation?.INV == true)` is better than `(investigation?.INV ?? false)`

Comment: I think Matt Beldon's on the right track here - we need to check if .INV is null also. so the whole thing is if (investigation?.INV ?? false)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - agree re. code not checking if property is null but if it is it should just return false, no? Rather than throw a null reference exception.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I think we agree, really. The code is OK but the description doesn't match it.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto because the OP said it could be

Comment: Edited to appease @CamiloTerevinto...  It doesn't check the properties to see if they're null, but if they are, it behaves like a 'try' and will skip the block without erroring out.

Comment: I think better phrasing might be "checks if the root object is null & if the property is null it evaluates to false and thus skips the block". I considered editing this in myself but given the discussion underway I thought it safest not to go edit things myself.

Comment: the statement `investigation?.INV == true` will implicitly check if `investigation?.INV` is null during its check. I only called out the null situation because I assume we all know what happens if `investigation?.INV` is either `true` or `false`. I'm not keen on your phrasing because its very unclear what you mean by "returns null if so". `investigation?.INV` evaluates to null but if it does that doesn't stop it doing the check. There is no `otherwise`. It will always check the value of `investigation?.INV` against true, no matter what input (the `==` is the only thing that can return a bool).

Answer (score 2):

In C# you can shorten it like so depending on what version you're limited to.

This one was my original and only answer, until it got marked down, but I prefer it because you can immediately see that .INV is nullable by the way it's written.  The last bottom answer, I believe is the most liked answer, but to me it says that either INV is nullable or the developer chooses to use `== true` in if statements (which I know some that do) and I just don't like that style of development.  It's a personal preference to me; unless someone can find a benefit using one over the other (such as performance strains in a loop or something.)

```
if (investigation?.INV ?? false)
{
    ....       
}
```

OR

```
if ((investigation?.INV).GetValueOrDefault())
{
    ....
}
```

OR

Although this may be the go to answer it's my least favorite only because I don't like adding `== true` to if statements.  Personal preference that's all.

```
if (investigation?.INV == true)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: @AlexWiese No, it's not. You cannot `if (bool?)`, only `if (bool)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto In his example he's also checking to see if INV is null so I'm assuming it's a nullable Boolean. If INV can be null then it's better to switch it to default; and in an if statement we don't need ```== true``` because it's always searching for true.

Comment: @AlexWiese ```?? false``` will switch a bool? to bool where if bool? is null it becomes false.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII You *do* need `== true` here because it's a `bool?` not a `bool`

Comment: What's so wrong with this answer? I think that's exactly how I would write it (but then again, I kinda hate the `== true` option. have hated if for a very, very long time now...)

Comment: @AlexWiese I took the ```== true``` out immediately after I answered because I copied and pasted it. Wasn't looking so you must have been in that quick moment seeing it.

Comment: Making it ```== true``` or ``` ?? false```  is just preference IMO.  Is there a penalty for choosing one over the other?

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes on this answer? I see nothing wrong with it!

Comment: Ok i just updated it with options... Seems like code preference can get a down vote around here when sometimes the result is the same.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You're correct about it needing ```== true``` where I said you didn't.

Answer (score -3):

It might be overkill but you can simply use

```
if((bool)investigation.INV)
{
   ...
}
```

in case INV is null you get the default value for the bool which is false...

ofc you should check if the investigation object isnt null or just simply use `investigation?.INV` in the higher C# versions.

Comment: That doesn't work if any of `Investigation` or `INV` is null.